# AWS SES python sqs.receive_message returning only one message output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using amazon ses python sdk to see how many messages are there in the queue for a given queue URL. in amazon GUI console i can see there are 3 messages within the queue for the queue URL. However i do not get more than 1 message as output everytime i run the command. Below is my code

```
import boto3
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def GetSecretKeyAndAccesskey():
    #code to pull secretkey and access key
    return(aws_access_key,aws_secret_key)
# Create SQS client
aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key = GetSecretKeyAndAccesskey()
sqs = boto3.client('sqs',aws_access_key_id=str(aws_access_key_id),aws_secret_access_key=str(aws_secret_access_key) ,region_name='eu-west-1')

response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl='my_queue_url',
    AttributeNames=[
        'All',
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=10,

)
print(response["Messages"][0])
```

Every time i run the code i get a different message id, and if i change my print code to check for the next list i get list index out of bound meaning that there is only one message

```
print(response["Messages"][1])
```

```
C:\>python testing.py
d4e57e1d-db62-4fc5-8233-c5576cb2603d

C:\>python testing.py
857858e9-55dc-4d23-aead-3c6622feccc5
```

Comment: Try polling the queue, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/sqs-example-long-polling.html

Comment: @StefanosAsl. no this does not work, still returns only one message

Comment: can you add the parameter MessageAttributeName and set it to ALL
`response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl='my_queue_url',
    AttributeNames=[
        'All',
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
    MessageAttributeNames= 'All'

)`

Comment: Also check for number of messages before trying to receive,
`response = client.get_queue_attributes(
    QueueUrl='string',
    AttributeNames=[
        'ApproximateNumberOfMessages'
    ]
)`

Comment: ApproximateNumberOfMessages is always correct, it matches what is there on Amazon console. however recieve message always shows one irrespective of what i have in  MaxNumberOfMessages.Setting MaxNumberOfMessages=10 also doesnt help.

Comment: did you try with using the `MessageAttributeNames= 'All' ` parameter in `sqs.receive_message` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add "WaitTimeSeconds" to turn on long polling and collect more messages during a single connection.

The other issue is that if you only put 3 messages on the queue, they get separated on the backend systems as part of the redundancy of the AWS SQS service.  So when you call to SQS, it connects you to one of the systems and delivers the single message that's available.  If you increase the number of total messages, you'll get more messages per request.

I wrote this code to demonstrate the functionality of SQS and allow you to play around with the concept and test.

```
import json

session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-east-2", profile_name="dev")
sqs = session.client('sqs')

def get_message():
    response = sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl='test-queue', MaxNumberOfMessages=10, WaitTimeSeconds=10)
    return len(response["Messages"])

def put_messages(seed):
    for message_number in range(seed):
        body = {"test": "message {}".format(message_number)}
        sqs.send_message(QueueUrl='test-queue', MessageBody=json.dumps(body))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    put_messages(2)
    print(get_message())
```